# Installing an apk running on armeabi-v7a on Android studio

Tags: installation, arm, apk, android-virtual-device, android-studio-2.1

I was running an API 33 pixel 6 x64_86 that returned an error for a couple of apps I was trying to install: [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

I found these run on armeabi-v7a. So I tried a second avd when I ran into a bunch of more problems.
The api 33 wouldnt run an armeabi-v7a, so I tried different combinations. Unfortunately every one of them had the same prompt that I should run an x86 image on an x86 host as its 10x faster. When I forced one to run on Nougat 7.1.1 armeabi-v7a, a nexus, the avd ran snail slow taking almost 10 mins to just start up and I could ultimately install neither of the apps.

Im now out of ideas. Can anyone help and mostly importantly, is there any way I can run the armeabi on the existing api33 x64_86 which is way faster?

Comment: Code? Im not a developer. I have a few apks of apps and a game that is built on the armv7a. I need help installing and being able to run them on my android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.

These are different instruction sets designed for different CPU hardware. `armeabi` is for Arm CPUs, and `x64_86` is for (e.g.) Intel/AMD CPUs.